# Strange behaviour in React-native-qrcode-SVG

Tags: react-native, qr-code

I'm using react-native-qrcode-svg.
The library seems to be working just fine, except that I got really strange styling:

[image]

I'm using it like that:

```
<QRCode
  getRef={(ref) => {this.svg = ref}}
  size={120}
  value={value}
/>
```

Comment: could you post a little bit more of your code? Maybe an example QR code you are using?

One thing I did notice is that you are setting the size to {120}, the default is 100, link to the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-svg#props 
Maybe that's messing up the styles.

Comment: the only solution I could find was to downgrade the react-native-svg version.. I tried the qr code with different values (also the ones from the given example) somehow the newer version seems to be buggy.

Comment: You should report your issue to the plugin's issues page at: https://github.com/awesomejerry/react-native-qrcode-svg/issues

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing helping was to downgrade     "react-native-svg" to version "11.0.1" and     "react-native-qrcode-svg" to  "5.3.2"

Seems like a bad solutions for this bug but at least it#s working..